# Cross Correlation for grouped Time Series

Tags: time-series, least-squares, causality, cross-correlation

I have two time series datasets that take place over a period of 7 years for a few thousand areas (7 data points for each area).

Which would look like:

```
t_1 : x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ... , x_m, y_m
t_2 : x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ... , x_m, y_m
...
t_n : x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ... , x_m, y_m
```

Where n in 7 and m is ~ 2,000

The first series is a time series of the number of fines issued, the second is a count of incidents. By incidents here we mean crimes that can cause a fine to be issued. I want to determine if the first series has an impact on the second series. i.e. do fines reduce the number of incidents?

I was planning on doing an cross correlation with different time lags. To determine which time lag (if any) shows correlation.

Does this analysis seem appropriate given my short time scale (7 data points)?